# Memory leak using NSMutableArray in RootViewController called from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, nsmutablearray, memory-leaks

I've written code to restore the state of my app, but there's a memory leak in the NSMutableArray. I'm new to Xcode so I apologize if this is something trivial I have overlooked. Any help is appreciated.
lq

```
AppDelegate.m

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [rootViewController restoreState];
}

RootViewController.h

@interface rootViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray  *offendingNSMutableArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *offendingNSMutableArray;

RootViewController.m

@synthesize offendingNSMutableArray;

- (void)restoreState {
    // Gets an array stored in the user defaults plist
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.offendingNSMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]    
            initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:kArrayValue]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.offendingNSMutableArray = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [offendingNSMutableArray release];
}
```

Comment: First, you alloc-init with retainCount=1, then you do setOffendingNSMutableArray: -> retainCount=2. In viewDidUnload you set it to nil, so retainCount=1, and you are loosing a pointer to your array. Here's your leak.

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to this... am I not alloc init and set in the same line with the following line of code:  
self.offendingNSMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]    
            initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:kArrayValue]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set it to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`, what are you going to release in `dealloc`? 
You should just do

```
self.offendingNSMutableArray = nil;
```

in `dealloc`, that's the common way for retained properties.

EDIT: See it now from the comment above. You need autorelease where you do alloc/init. Property setter will do retain.

Comment: Using Instruments I'm showing Leaked Object: Malloc 32 Bytes on the alloc init line as well as Leaked Object: NSCFArray on the alloc init line.

Comment: I am told (by eminent Obj-C folk around here) that calling property setters in `dealloc` is a bad idea because it may lead to notifications firing, which you don't want in mid teardown. As for the memory leak -- there certainly is one, see @beefon's comment.

Comment: @walkytalky this is what is recommended here http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProperties.html. Yes, I see the leak now, my bad

Comment: The section on dealloc in that very document says: "Note: Typically in a dealloc method you should release object instance variables directly (rather than invoking a set accessor and passing nil as the parameter)". There's an exception for the synthetic ivar case, where direct release is not an option, but otherwise that seems pretty unambiguous.

Comment: well, go ahead and read the next sentence. Of course everyone is using modern runtime and synthesizing, what else?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like I solve the leak by adding autorelease:

```
- (void)restoreState {
    // Gets an array stored in the user defaults plist
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.offendingNSMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]    
        initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:kArrayValue]] autorelease];
}
```

But I thought I didn't want to use autorelease because I reference offendingNSMutableArray in other places in the app?

Comment: The setter will `retain` the object for itself. This `autorelease` relinquishes the local ownership you got via `alloc`. Putting it all in one line like that makes the semantics a bit opaque -- it'd be clearer to `alloc`/`init` in one line, assign in a second and then explicitly `release` in a third -- but the end result is (nearly) the same.